# how to make the list of paths of all descender files of a directory in php?

Tags: php

Please let me know how to make a list of paths of all descendant files of a directory in php,so that you can copy them to another directory?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php - Might help you

Comment: No. This isn't http://gimme-teh-codez.com

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

Answer (score 1):

Use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) if you want to be specific about file/directory names